# Daily Partitioning and archiving

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to partition a table by month say Jan, Feb, Mar. The column through which I'll partition is a `datetime` type column with an ISO Format (`'20190101'`, `'20190201'`, etc).

For example, I have sales data for jan, feb, mar. I'd like the data to be partitioned by daily partitioned . (`'20190101'`, `'20190201'`,`'20190301'` etc)

E.X:

Jan, Feb, Mar etc. Also I would like to keep the data less so I would like to delete daily day wise data keeping only 1 month data maximum, for example I will create jan 31 , feb 28 , mar 31, apr 30. How do I manage partition dynamically as some month is 31 days some are 28 days and 30 days. Also I need to retain only one month data for example if its, 1st of sep then I need to keep aug 31 days data, and can delete 31st jul day data now on 2nd sep I can delete 1st august data so I need to delete daily data and keep only 30 days data .

My question is: is it even possible? If it is, how an I automate the process using SSIS?

Comment: *"The Column through which I'll partition is a datetime type column with an ISO Format"* Date and time data types in SQL Server have *no* format (this is true for the older `datetime` data type and the newer like `date` and `datetime2`). If it's a `datetime`, it's stored as a binary value, if it has a format then it's a `(n)varchar`. It be a `datetime` value **and** have a format.

Comment: yes i can change to datetime2 and how to dynamically do this

Comment: I didn't say anything about changing the data type.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, if you have a column that is of type `datetime` then you could simply use the `MONTH()` function on it to partition by month.

Comment: How to manage months like some months are 28days , 31 days and 30 days?

Comment: @sandeep you wanted to partition by month, so using the `MONTH()` function will accommodate that. That function knows how many days are in each month and will partition by January, February, etc. If you want to partition by a fixed number of days, that's a different method altogether.

Comment: Is your question about partitioning (when you "delete" data by switching partitions) or do you want just to DELETE some data?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. As you want to remove previous 30 days data from current date or any specific date, so you can easily calculate the date range by subtracting 30 days from the current date.

For 30 days

```
--- Instead of getdate() you may use any of your date column for filter
delete from yourtable where yourdate < DATEADD( day, -30, getdate())   ---- here on place of 30 you may use any days you want to delete
```

For 1 month

```
--- Instead of getdate() you may use any of your date column for filter
delete from yourtable where yourdate < DATEADD( month, -1, getdate())   ---- here on place of 30 you may use any days you want to delete
```

Comment: Thanks, One more question how do i dynamically create month partitions ar feb is 28 days, and few months are 30 days and 31 days,For example if i create 31days every month then in feb month i will have 3days of empty partition and other months 1day of empty partition.

Comment: don't go by days then...use second option month. Actually date is not your concern in that case, you want the record of last moth. Hope that'll clear your doubt.

Comment: yes agreed thanks you i can use 2nd option.I would like to ask how do i create daily partitions for jan,feb .march april....dec months dynamically becuse jan i have to create 31 partition ,feb i have to create 28days like that how to create dynamically.

Comment: @sandeep: that is kind of extension of this question....but still it is unclear what is your expected output...you can mark this as accepted as it answers your current question and create new thread for this part....and please post your sample input and expected output......also you can share to me so I can get the notification and give you quick response.......Happy to help...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your partition boundaries be the end of the month, have them be the beginning. That is, do something like:

```
[2019-01-01, 2019-02-01),
[2019-02-01, 2019-03-01),
[2019-03-01, 2019-04-01),
[2019-04-01, 2019-05-01),
[2019-05-01, 2019-06-01),
etc
```

That is, the left-hand boundary is in the partition and the right-hand boundary isn't. If you're using actual Partitioning, you'd define your partition function as a "boundary left" function. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more details.